# Struts 1.3 iterate once for special property in table

Tags: struts, struts-1

I've got a tbody in my .jsp file:

```
    <tbody>
        <logic:iterate name="tableList" property="list" id="e">
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="A" /></td>
                <td class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="B" /></td>
                <td class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="C" /></td>
            </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
    </tbody>
```

I want to iterate my property "A" only once, but "B" and "C" iterate normally.
Is any way to do that?

I tried verify it in java class, and when my A property has only one item I used rowspan, but when I wanted to:

```
<td rowspan="12" class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="A" /></td>
```

it can't work too (whole table is destroyed).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter on the indexId attribute and test with logic:equal or jstl c:if like this :

`<c:if test="${condition}">
     condition  is true 
</c:if>`

Below the code

```
<tbody>
    <logic:iterate name="tableList" property="list"  indexId="ctr" id="e">
        <tr class="text-center">

            <logic:equal name="ctr" value="0" >
                <td class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="A" /></td>
            </logic:equal>
            <td class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="B" /></td>
            <td class="text-center"><bean:write name="e" property="C" /></td>
        </tr>
    </logic:iterate>
```